# Redux saga typescript type error in yield all

Tags: typescript, redux-saga

I'm trying very simple example from redux-saga page.

```
function* saga(): SagaIterator {
  yield takeEvery(T.GET_CREDENTIALS, getCredentials);
}

export default function* rootSaga() {
  yield all([
    saga(),
  ]);
}
```

But I get typescript error:

```
Argument of type 'IterableIterator<RootEffect | TakeEffect | 
ChannelTakeEffect<any> | PutEffect<any> | ChannelPutEf...' is not 
assignable to parameter of type '{ [key: string]: Effect; }'.
Index signature is missing in type 'IterableIterator<RootEffect | 
TakeEffect | ChannelTakeEffect<any> | PutEffect<any> | 
ChannelPutEf...'.
```

What I'm doing wrong? Thanks for help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since links to solutions apparently get downvoted, this is the solution:

```
export default function* rootSaga() {
  yield all([
    call(saga()),
  ]);
}
```

Comment: It wasn't me who downvoted. Anyway I also started discussion on github. And it's seems to be agreed solution. https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga/issues/1044#issuecomment-312509142

Comment: `call(saga())` ---> `call(saga)`, it should

Answer (score 2):

The examples in the redux-saga repository mostly use this form:

```
export default function* rootSaga() {
    yield all([
        fork(saga1),
        fork(saga2),
        // ...
    ])
}
```

See for instance their [real-world example](https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga/blob/master/examples/real-world/sagas/index.js).
I'm not sure what the point is of using `fork` instead of `call` when we are using `all` around it, since that helper alone should ensure parallel execution.